# How to Get the font color of an Excel Cell in c#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

okay, so I'm trying to get the cell's font color as the program needs to do different things biased on the font color in the cell so I made a test file

[image: how the cells look inside excel]

and I tried to access it like so:

```
Range thrange = ws.UsedRange.Columns["A:A", Type.Missing].Rows;
foreach (Range r in thrange)
{
   Style sy = r.Style;
   Font font = sy.Font;
   ColorFormat color = (ColorFormat)font.Color;
   Console.WriteLine("  "+r.Value+"  " + color.RGB);
}
```

I get
`Can not convert type 'double' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ColorFormat'`

I saw people saying you set the color with a drawing object so I tried changing the last two lines to:

```
Color color =(System.Drawing.Color)font.Color;
Console.WriteLine("  "+r.Value+"  " + color.ToArgb());
```

but that didn't work either
`Can not convert type 'double' to 'System.Drawing.Color'`

so I thought I'd see what this double is, then set the font to a known rgb value and work out how to convert the number I get back into that. but that didn't work either.
as while
`Console.WriteLine("  "+r.Value+" "+r.style.font.color);`
didn't throw an error it still didn't give me anything useful:

```
 cyan 0
 pink 0
 blue 0
 red 0
 orange 0
 purple 0
```

I thought maybe `r.style.font.colorindex` but that just gave me a 1 for everything instead of a 0
I was hopping for something like

```
 blue 0000ff
 red ff0000
```

I can't use a 3rd party libraries due to the rules set out by the project owner.

So how do I get the actual color value out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Font` property of the `Range` not that of its `Style`. Then use the `ColorTranslator` class to convert the double `value` from Office to a .net `Color`.

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range r in thrange)
{
    // Get Color from Font from Range directly
    int oleColor = Convert.ToInt32(r.Font.Color);
   
    // Convert to C# Color type
    System.Drawing.Color c = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(oleColor);

    // Output
    Console.WriteLine(r.Value + " " + c.ToString());
}
```

Comment: ooh yes! thanks that gets into something I can work with.